# How can i get a maximum item on the same line using DAX of PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to get the maximum value's label on the line of table on PowerBI. But I have no idea how to resolve it. How can i get a maximum item on the same line using DAX of PowerBI?

before the table.

```
item1 item2 item3
100 110 200
80 110 35
250 310 635
```

ideal result

```
item1 item2 item3 maxItem
100 110 200 item3
80 110 35 item2
250 310 635 item3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a function that can directly return a column name. but you can try out this [return the column name based on max value](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-return-the-column-name-based-on-max-value/m-p/328072#M146458)